# Error in using action-bar inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

i need to use action bar button inside fragment.so i am trying to implement by using option menu item but it's showing following error.............

```
 - 02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.t3chtr3ndz.sportz/info.tech.slidermenu.slider_main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class fragment
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class fragment
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at info.tech.slidermenu.slider_main.onCreate(slider_main.java:61)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     ... 11 more
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at info.tech.slidermenu.slider_main.onPrepareOptionsMenu(slider_main.java:219)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.app.Activity.onPreparePanel(Activity.java:2494)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPrepareOptionsPanel(FragmentActivity.java:491)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPreparePanel(FragmentActivity.java:480)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:421)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:747)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2595)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:648)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:803)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at info.tech.slidermenu.Home_feed.onCreateView(Home_feed.java:93)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
02-22 13:40:27.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     ... 24 more
02-22 13:42:02.621: E/Trace(2902): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

### Class

```
            public class Home_feed extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = "title";
        ActionBar bar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                com.t3chtr3ndz.sportz.R.layout.home_feed, container, false);
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu_home);
        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(0, -1)));

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(1, -1)));

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(2, -1)));

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(3, -1)));

        navMenuIcons.recycle();
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getActivity(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActivity().getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);


            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);


            }

        };
        ListView listview = (ListView) rootView
                .findViewById(com.t3chtr3ndz.sportz.R.id.Home_feed_list);
        listview.setAdapter(new adapter(getActivity()));

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item

            Log.i("click", "unsuccess");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i("item", "" + item.getItemId());
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            Log.i("item", "action icon");
            return true;

        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my xml file.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gray" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment2"
                android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment3"
                android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class fragment` - post your XML

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at info.tech.slidermenu.slider_main.onPrepareOptionsMenu(slider_main.java:219)

Comment: @darnmason ....problem in creating menu...mat be...check it...noo

Comment: Thrs a null you are getting place a log and find out why.. line 219. In d slide menu file

Comment: at line no 219 code is like this......                             boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList); it is inside of onprepare option menu methode....

Comment: @bhavdip Debug it, mDrawerLayout must be null

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a Null Pointer error, in this function:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

My guess is that mDrawerLayout is null. Why might it be null?

1. The id file was wrong- Doesn't look like this is the case, I checked it out.
2. onCreate() wasn't called yet. I can't prove this, but it could be the case.
3. The content view wasn't set right. It looks right, but it's hard to tell.

Bottom line, I'd see what `mDrawLayout` is equal to, and if null, figure out why it was never set. If it's not the null value, figure out what is set.